# Add-ins displayed in outlook 2010 is not displayed in outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

The issue occurs in outlook 2013 which is working perfectly in outlook 2010.

The add-ins which were displayed in outlook main screen is not displayed during new email, reply email, forward email etc...

The same add-ins is displayed in outlook 2010 in both main screen and new/reply/forward email page.

I have selected the add-ins from options. But still issue exist.

The code used is C#.Net. Is this outlook 2013 issue or code issue. As it works other versions of outlook except outlook 2013.

Please help me out on this to, find what could be the issue? solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what the exact problem could be without knowing what your dependent components are or how the add-in is deployed.  Are you accessing any objects, properties or methods that may have been dropped from the Outlook 2013 Object Model (like Contact linking)?

If this is Outlook 64-bit, is your add-in 64-bit compatible?

Comment: The outlook 2013 is 32-bit and the add-in are 32-bit compatible.

Comment: Is the add-in loaded? Or are certain UI components not displaying?  You really need to provide more details about what the add-in is trying to do, what components are used, how it is deployed, etc.

Comment: The add-in is loaded and displayed in outlook main screen but not loaded and displayed in new email/ reply email/ forward email in add-in tab. the add-in will be added to outlook while the application is installed in the machine where the office installed.

Comment: If your add-in is loaded, then the problem lies with your code. It sounds like you are trying to display a Task Pane or some other UI in a new email Inspector window.  Please show your code that is failing to display your UI and what explain in more detail what this UI is, when and where it should be displayed and what it does.